# Convert model.fit_generator to model.fit

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I have codes in the following,

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
```

Now `model.fit_generator` is defined as following:

```
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

Now `model.fit_generator` is deprecated, what is the proper way to change `model.fit_generator` to `model.fit` in this case?

Comment: By the way, steps_per_epoch = int(steps_per_epoch/batch_size). Your code is not valid for the latest versions of TensorFlow(Keras inside TensorFlow).

Comment: @TimbusCalin What is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is that steps_per_epoch should be equal to the number of training samples divided to the batch_size, not the total number of training samples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to change `model.fit_generator()` to `model.fit()`.

As of TensorFlow 2.1, `model.fit()` also accepts generators as input. As simple as that.

From TensorFlow's official documentation:

> Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future
>   version. Instructions for updating: Please use Model.fit, which
>   supports generators.

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of 'generator='.

###### Old training:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2048//36, epochs=10,
    validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=832//16)
```

###### New training:

```
model.fit(train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2048 // 128, epochs=10,
    validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=832//16)
```

Comment: What does this answer provide that the accepted answer doesn't?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts because it declarative, while accepted one is imperative

Comment: Actually this answer helped me. After changing fit_generator to fit, I got error message that 'generator=' is unknown. @HKMSN shows that.